# Nothing is Displaying on my browser after running npm start in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

after installing react-router-dom version 6 I tried to run npm start but I get a blank page with no error in my console. Below the first code is the code for the screen I want to display. Please can someone help me and show me what I am not doing correctly here.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import MovieList from './component/movieList';

import  { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path = "/welcome" element = {MovieList}/>
    </Routes>
    </Router>
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

```
import { useState } from "react";

function MovieList() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("")
  const [movies, setMovie] = useState([])
  const handleMovieSearchChange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const fetchMovie = (movieName) => {
    const searchUrl = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${movieName}&page=2&apikey=2c2c85ae`;

    fetch(searchUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setMovie(result.Search);
      });
  };

  const movieItems = movies.map((movie, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
       <img src={movie.Poster} alt="" />
        <h3>{movie.Title}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Movie List Page</h1>Search
      <input type={"text"} onChange={handleMovieSearchChange} />
      <button onClick={() => fetchMovie(searchTerm)}>Search</button>
      {movieItems}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MovieList;
```

Comment: which page are you trying to hit in the browser?

Comment: The MovieList page

Comment: I added the code for the page I wanted to display on the browser

Comment: whats the url you're opening in browser?

Comment: The `MovieList` component is rendered at `/movie` path, have you tried checking if the component is rendered at `/movie` ?

Comment: I just ran npm start and it opened an empty page at localhost3000

Comment: @JoelStephen when you run npm start it goes to "/" route  and you have not rendered any component on this route there inside your code & in your application "/welcome" route shows your movielist, So go to "localhost:3000/welcome" and then see.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a blank white screen because you are not rendering any component/page for the home route `/`. When the react application render initially renders the page which has `path="/"`. there are two ways to fix it you can either render your welcome page at path `/` or you can redirect the user to the welcome screen if the user hits the home or `/` path.

**First Method**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import MovieList from './component/movieList';

import  { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path = "/" element = {MovieList}/>
    </Routes>
    </Router>
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**Second Method**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import MovieList from './component/movieList';

import  { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path = "/welcome" element = {MovieList}/>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/welcome" />} />
    </Routes>
    </Router>
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: The first one did not solve the problem, it did not return any error on the console and did not also return anything on the browser. So I uninstalled version 6 and installed version 5 and used the Switch instead of the Routes and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a componet:  `<Route exact path = "/welcome" element = {MovieList}/>`

instead  `<Route exact path = "/welcome" element = {<MovieList/>}/>`